# Change image Floating Action Button Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I used this library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button. How can I change the image of the main button? I want to change the button image right after selecting one of the smaller buttons.

Comment: I got the same problem and its all snatching my hair. Thanks for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35697105/5228412
it works fine for me and wish for others who'll reach here.

Answer (score 58):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

> As this class descends from ImageView, you can control the icon which
>   is displayed via setImageDrawable(Drawable).

Or you can use setImageResource():

```
fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_white);
```

Answer (score 37):

you can use this in your .XML :

```
android:src="@drawable/icon" // change backgroung icon
app:backgroundTint="@color/icons" // change background color
```

use this in code:

```
 mFloatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_btn);

// State 1 -on

fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.fab_on));

// State  2 - off

fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.fab_off));
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue recently, I tried with following option

```
  fab:fab_icon="@drawable/icon"
```

and

```
 android:src="@drawable/icon" // change backgroung icon
```

even tried programmatically

```
 fab_menu_btn.setImageResource();
```

Nothing worked.

Solution: In app's build.gradle file  replace

```
  compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.github.toanvc:floatingactionmenu:0.8.9'
```

In .xml file Use:

```
           <toan.android.floatingactionmenu.FloatingActionsMenu
          </toan.android.floatingactionmenu.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

In activity File:

```
      floatingActionsMenu.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.icon));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Material design version:

- build.gradle (app)

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true // For srcCompat
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
}
```

- XML (for set icon)

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_google"
app:tint="@color/colorGoogle"
```

More documentation: https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, this will be:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private fun pauseTimer() {
floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow))
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately with this library you can't change the icon from the menu (see issues from this library from more info)

That is why I dropped this library to use a way more flexible one! It is originally a fork but it is now more advanced.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I managed to create my own solution. Maybe some else founds it also useful. I have posted the complete answer to another question ([How to set an icon to getbase FloatingActionsMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838562/how-to-set-icon-to-getbase-floatingactionsmenu/37033749#37033749)) but this part posted here is relevant to the question in dynamically changing the main menu button picture/image when one of the sub buttons is chosen. In this case, you need o combine the answer from the "linked question" and the answer below.

In order to change the icon on the menu button when you choose a floatingActionButton it can be implemented like this:

Create menu button in xml file, create floating button(s) on .java file (programmatically) set menu button (color button, color pressed button and image). Then simply add all buttons to the menu button. You can also deactivate the animation of the menu button by simply commenting out the code in `FloatingActionsMenu` class.

Then every time that you create a button, sample:

```
final FloatingActionButton actionA = new FloatingActionButton(getBaseContext());
        actionA.setTitle("Familie");
        actionA.setIcon(R.drawable.world_map);
        actionA.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
        actionA.setColorNormalResId(R.color.red);
        actionA.setColorPressedResId(R.color.black_semi_transparent);
        actionA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                menuMultipleActions.setMenuButton(R.drawable.icon, R.color.red_transparent, R.color.black_semi_transparent);
                Toast.makeText(MainMapView.this, "Action Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ((FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions)).collapse();
                return;
            }
        });
```

See the answer posted on the link on how to configure the classes and define the menu button and floating button(s).

So the important part to notice here is:

```
menuMultipleActions.setMenuButton(R.drawable.icon, R.color.red_transparent, R.color.black_semi_transparent);
```

This method you need to add in the `FloatingActionsMenu` class. Simply you call the method after on every floatingActionButton you want to update the image.

More information you can find on the link that I have posted. So when you click one of the floatingActionButton(s).

For the moment the color on the menu button is not updating correctly but I am working on it if I find a solution I will update the answer here as well. Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: Is there a reason for the -1, or just for fun? Someone tried this solution and it did not work for him?

Comment: I voted -1 because it didn't work for me. In fact , some time after i voted I tried to unvote it, because it's not cool but i wasn't allowed to ... So, sorry :/

Answer (score -4):

Add the property

```
fab:fab_icon="@drawable/fab_expand"
```

in the xml where you initialized the floating action menu.

Comment: Hey this property doesn´t exist!        fab:fab_icon

Comment: this answer was for custom library futuresimple, not for standard FAB