# Android Icons Library

Tags: android, icons, material-design

Folks, is there a free library of icons based on Material Design, I am working on an app and i want my floating button to have a camera icon, an edit icon and so on. Is there such a place to dowbnload free icon images?

thanks

Comment: "material design icons" in google. second link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30455765/1939564

Comment: https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: Good question :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes of course. Google itself offers a whole bunch of icons:
https://material.io/tools/icons/

This website here offers a better way of looking and downloading the icons + there are even a few free icons created by the community.
http://materialdesignicons.com/

Comment: http://materialdesignicons.com/ is the best...

Answer (score 3):

Google material design official site:
https://material.io/icons/

Free to use Apache license

You can use this library as well to avoid the burden of downloading and adding each icon into your project:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2193