# android: dynamically change FAB(Floating Action Button) icon from code

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

How to change FAB icon in an Activity during runtime. I have this code ->

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabMainActivity);
```

I know this is possible using `fab.setBackgroundDrawable();` but i am a newbie to android, don't understand how to do this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `fab. setBackground` ?

Comment: I am unable to do that.. as it expect a drawable.. and idk how to make a drawable ??

Comment: Have you added icon in Drawable folder? if yes then just pass `R.drawable.<icon_name>` to `setBackground` method otherwise first add icon to drawable folder then do same

Comment: passing `R.drawable.<icon_name>` to `fab.setBackgroundDrawable();` gives an error... `setBackgroundDrawable (android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) in FloatingActionButton can not be applied to (int)`

Comment: Ok do it as: `Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable. icon_name); fab .setBackground(dr`awable)l

Comment: Yes its working, but `getDrawable` is deprecated... in API level 22 instead we should use `getDrawable (int id, Resources.Theme theme)`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Changing FloatingActionButton source:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_full_sad, context.getTheme()));
        } else {
            floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_full_sad));
    }
```

This can be replaced by following code from the support library instead:

```
floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_full_sad));
```

Comment: Try to avoid `getApplicationContext` as much as possible

Comment: @zozelfelfo why is that?

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Activity context can cause memory leaks depending on how you are using it. Typically it's the activity context that is troublesome because it can cause memory leaks. If the activity dies and another object has a reference to that activity via the context it can't be garbage collected. However, there are some cases when you want to use the activity context over the app context, [ex](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29).

Comment: How can I set an icon to an Extended FAB programmatically?

Answer (score 21):

If you are using the Support Library:

```
floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_name)
```

Comment: This should be the marked answer since with this use can use vectors

Answer (score 18):

Or you use the Support Library:

```
floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_full_sad));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you will use the image `ic_arrow_forward.png` as your fab's background:

```
fab.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_arrow_forward);
```

Comment: If you use R.drawable.* or R.mipmap.*, using `setImageResource` is far more straight forward. I think this answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

What I am using as follows,

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_btn);

// State 1 -on

fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.fab_on));

// State  2 - off

fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.fab_off));
```