# how to change FAB default picture

Tags: android

I checked api and set `src background` or foreground for `FAB` but always showing same as image below. I want to replace default red button.

[image]

Comment: check it for solution <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455765/change-image-floating-action-button-android>.

Comment: i do the same thing but the result not change,my picture looks  too small and in center of default red button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it programatically by  doing  this:

```
fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

or you can do this in the xml

```
android:src="@drawable/icon" // change your background icon
app:backgroundTint="@color/icons" // change your background color
```

Comment: i do the same thing but my picture  is too small and in center of the default red button