# How to Change Image in fab

Tags: android, fragment, floating-action-button, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

When I change `fragment` my `FAB (FloatingActionButton)` not change her image. I've got this method to change image:

```
private void fabImages(){
    final NavHostFragment nhf = (NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    if(nhf != null){
        Fragment fragmentActual = nhf.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
        if(fragmentActual instanceof  HomeFragment){
            binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_auto_blanco);
        }else if(fragmentActual instanceof GalleryFragment){
            binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save);
        }
    }
}
```

i'm using this activity to my app:

[image]

I apply this method in `onCreate` and `onResume` from my `MainActivity` but the image not change, why?

**UPDATE:**

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private String horaString, fechaString;
    private NombreTallerPreferencia nombreTallerPreferencia;
    private PermissionHelper permissionHelper;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

    public static final String TAG = "logcat";
    public static final String BARRA = "/";

    private View view_imagen_perfil;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);

        fabImages(); //method to change image

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fabImages(); //method to change image
    }
```

Comment: please show some of code

Comment: i'd updated the answer, thanks! @Ajithkumarmuthukumaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in how to set a drawable to the FAB, because you already do that right. But the problem in the place where you do that which is in `onResume()`.

**Here is the scenario:**

- The app is launched, onResume() get triggered, and the `fabImages()` get called, so, it's `HomeFragment`, so set `R.drawable.ic_add_auto_blanco`, and this works with you.
- You go to `GalleryFragment`, so `HomeFragment` is hidden now and the `GalleryFragment` is shown, but here the `onResume()` of the activity won't get called, because the activity is not paused() i.e. onPause() doesn't get called;
- While you're at `GalleryFragment`, If you change the configuration by rotating the device, then `onResume()` will get called, and so as `fabImages()`, and fab changes its drawable to `R.drawable.ic_save`.

So, you need to call `fabImages()` somewhere else other than the `onResume` of the activity.

To fix this you need to register a listener in the activity that tracks whenever the navigation changes its current destination, and that through the  `OnDestinationChangedListener` interface:

So, in your activity's `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);

    fabImages(); //method to change image

    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    
    
    
    /////////////////////////
    // Here is the new code:
    /////////////////////////
    
    NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener destinationChangedListener = new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
                binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_auto_blanco);

            } else if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                binding.appBarMain.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save);
            }
        }
    };

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(destinationChangedListener);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your application does not have fallback conditional like **else** just incase your values are null.
You can read more about changing the icon on FAB here on
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32082108/12028348 or from the official android studio documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html